# Configuring a MongoDB Cluster

Tags: mongodb, docker, cluster-computing, mongodb-replica-set

I should configure a mongodb cluster with two nodes. Each node should have all data replicated. If one server die, the other should assume as primary.

Before I configure the cluster, I'm doing a local test using docker instances to configure it. [As I saw in the documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/), I should have at least 3 instances of MongoDB. Is that correct?

First I created the tree instance with docker, the I configured the instance one to be the primary. The code bellow is my docker compose and the configure script.

The Docker compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
    mongo-2:
        container_name: mongo-2
        image: mongo:4
        ports:
            - 30102:27017
        command: mongod --replSet cnf-serv --port 27017 --oplogSize 16 --bind_ip_all
        restart: always

    mongo-3:
        container_name: mongo-3
        image: mongo:4
        ports:
            - 30103:27017
        command: mongod --replSet cnf-serv --port 27017 --oplogSize 16 --bind_ip_all
        restart: always 

    mongo-1:
        container_name: mongo-1
        image: mongo:4
        ports:
            - 30101:27017
        command: mongod --replSet cnf-serv --port 27017 --oplogSize 16 --bind_ip_all
        links:
            - mongo-2:mongo-2
            - mongo-3:mongo-3
        restart: always

    mongo-setup:
        container_name: mongo-setup
        image: mongo:4
        depends_on:
            - mongo-1
            - mongo-2
            - mongo-3
        links:
            - mongo-1:mongo-1
            - mongo-2:mongo-2
            - mongo-3:mongo-3
        volumes:
            - ./scripts:/scripts
        environment: 
            - MONGO1=mongo-1
            - MONGO2=mongo-2
            - MONGO3=mongo-3
            - RS=cnf-serv
            - PORT=27017
        entrypoint: [ "/scripts/setup.sh" ]
```

The configure script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

mongodb1=`getent hosts ${MONGO1} | awk '{ print $1 }'`
mongodb2=`getent hosts ${MONGO2} | awk '{ print $1 }'`
mongodb3=`getent hosts ${MONGO3} | awk '{ print $1 }'`

port=${PORT:-27017}

echo "Waiting for startup.."
until mongo --host ${mongodb1}:${port} --eval 'quit(db.runCommand({ ping: 1 }).ok ? 0 : 2)' &>/dev/null; do
printf '.'
sleep 1
done

echo "Started.."

echo setup.sh time now: `date +"%T" `
mongo --host ${mongodb1}:${port} <<EOF
var cfg = {
        "_id": "${RS}",
        "protocolVersion": 1,
        "members": [
            {
                "_id": 100,
                "host": "${mongodb1}:${port}"
            },
            {
                "_id": 101,
                "host": "${mongodb2}:${port}"
            },
            {
                "_id": 102,
                "host": "${mongodb3}:${port}"
            }
        ]
    };
    rs.initiate(cfg, { force: true });
    rs.reconfig(cfg, { force: true });
EOF
```

When I try to connect in any external container port, I have the same error message: `Could not connect to MongoDB on the provided host and port`

How can I configure a internal cluster using docker?

Comment: Wait for several seconds in the setup.sh. Mongodb needs some time to spin up and start listening on the port after container successfully started and appeared available for dependants.

Answer (score 1):

A 2-node replica set won't be very much help; if one of the nodes goes down, then the other node can't take over as primary because it can't command a majority of votes in the election. You get some benefit in that you have a full copy of the data on the second node, but to get the full benefit of your replica set (both redundancy and high-availability), you would need to add a 3rd node.